# shortcut to check if variable is null || undefined || empty string || false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, shortcut

I am looking for check, if my variable is one of :

```
null || undefined || empty string || false
```

Right now its look messy and long:

```
const userHasPhoneNumber = user.phone === undefined || 
                           user.phone === "" || 
                           user.phone === false ||
                           user.phone === null ? false : true;
```

Is there shortcut?

Comment: Just try `const userHasPhoneNumber = !!user.phone;`

Comment: What kind of data is this, where it's completely valid, to have a phone number be any one of these? Something doesn't seem right here.

Answer (score 3):

Use JavaScript's [`!!`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript), witch will become `false` for `null`, `""`, `undefined` and `false`:

```js
const user = {
  phone_1: null,
  phone_2: "",
  phone_3: undefined,
  phone_4: false
};

console.log(!!user.phone_1);  // false
console.log(!!user.phone_2);  // false
console.log(!!user.phone_3);  // false
console.log(!!user.phone_4);  // false
```

**Note** Use this with caution as some results may be different then expected, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10597474/5625547) shows a complete list.

Comment: …but also for some other values.

Comment: Thabk u. My phone variables has checked before so je can be only undefined or empty or if user enter phone so it already a number of length 10 exactly

Comment: This function  hasPHonenumber that i mentioned is for show modal if user dont have phone number

Answer (score 1):

If you coerce that string to a boolean then it should check all your conditions, which is pretty much checking if `user.phone` is truthy.

It depends how you want to use it. If you wanted to use it in a condition, i.e. `if(userHasPhoneNumber) ...` then you can use the string directly : `if(user.phone)` as it will coerce to a boolean.

If you really need to have a boolean variable then need to cast it to a boolean explicitely:

Either through
`const userHasPhoneNumber = Boolean(user.phone);`
or
`const userHasPhoneNumber = !!user.phone;`

Note, as  @Bergi commented, that there are more values that are coerced to a false value (falsy values), for example `NaN` or the number `0` (the string "0" will coerce to true), so it depends what your input is. If it's never a number but either a string/boolean/`null`/`undefined`, it should be fine. Here is the list of all falsy values for reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: Different result for `0` and `NaN`

Comment: Thank.  Take a look in my comment for 0stone0

Answer (score 1):

You can shortcut `x === undefined || x === null` to `x == null`. For the others, there is no shortcut as there are some falsy number values as well. You could however do

```
const userHasPhoneNumber = typeof user.phone == "number" || !!user.phone
```

Comment: simple and elegant